# Use Dense layer directly

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

In [this file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py) there is a definition of a `Dense` layer, as well as its functional counterpart, `dense`. I get how to use `dense`; but in my case I need to apply the same dense layer several times to different inputs; it seems to me that using `Dense` directly would be more convenient than fiddling with `reuse`; however, I am unable to use it:

`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.layers.layers' has no attribute 'Dense'`

There is also no documentation on it; does it mean that I cannot do this and will have to use a very unconvenient setup with tricky `reuse`s?